# python virtual env specific to every execution of an azkaban flow

Tags: python, virtualenv, azkaban

I've multiple azkaban flows in a project. Most of the commands are python scripts and all of them are running in a scheduled way.
job nodes look like this :

```
nodes:
  - name: Start
    type: command
    config:
      command: printenv

  - name: Install Python Requirements
    type: command
    config:
      command: pip3 install -r requirements.txt
    dependsOn:
      - Start

  - name: CustomLogic
    type: command
    config:
      command: python3 test.py
    dependsOn:
      - Install Python Requirements
```

There are intermittent errors in the scheduled executions where the second step fails.
I was wondering it might be because i'm using global python in my commands.

Is there a nice extensible way i can spawn a new python virtualenv before all my executions and run them in it?